# Get rid of added space to my headers when using .grouped tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

[image: Image shows white border added when tableview is set to .grouped.]I made the tableview .grouped so that the headers would not be sticky. However, that results in adding extra padding at the top and bottom of the tableview (which I fixed), as well as extra space on top of my header views. Online it seems like the only thing ppl are talking about is getting rid of the header, but the header is why I made it grouped as that stops it from sticking. How do I get rid of the 20 or so pixels of padding that .grouped adds to all headers without getting rid of my header views? Undoing the .grouped setting gets rid of the white space. Is that the only way as I want to keep it grouped?

You'd think Apple would make this easier.

I colored my header red to highlight the unwanted white space above. Changing the height for row at of the cell does not affect the white area.

Comment: michaeldebo did you ever find a solution to this? I want to use section headers (that are inline and not sticky), like you, but I don't want the extra grey padding added by apple once I set the tableview's style to `.grouped`

Answer (score 1):

This will get rid of the headerView and footerView for the overall tableView:

```
    tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude, y: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude, y: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```

Then to individually set the height to 0 for the section headers, you have to use the following function:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }
```

And for the footer per section, similarly:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but that doesn't fix the problem of extra white space above my section headers.

Comment: When I try that it gets rid of the header that I made and want to display, but leaves behind the white space that I'm trying to get rid of. I must be doing something wrong because I can't be the first person to have this problem on stack overflow. Tableviews have been around for years...

Comment: Can you post a picture so we can get a clearer idea?

Comment: Done. I colored my header red to highlight the unwanted white space. Changing the heightForRowAt did not affect this white space.

Comment: The white space seems to be a footerView problem. Did you set the height of the footerView to leastNonZeroMagnitude?

Comment: This is in my code: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }

Comment: I've just tested it and it works for me. If you share all of your code, I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, put this code inside the viewDidLoad() `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -35, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.setupTableView() 
}

func setupTableViews() {
   tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -35, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) 
}
```